# is the abelianization functor (on groups) full?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

By abelianization I mean, for any group $G$, its commutator subgroup is the subgroup $[G,G]$ generated by elements of the form $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ for $g,h\in G$.

Then the abelianization of $G$ is $G^{\text{ab}} := G/[G,G]$.

For any two groups $X,Y$, by functoriality we have a map
$$\text{Hom}(X,Y)\rightarrow\text{Hom}(X^{\text{ab}},Y^{\text{ab}})$$

My question is, is this map always surjective for any two groups $X,Y$?

Comment: What about $X=A_5$, and $Y=S_5$?

Comment: I don't actually know if that's a counterexample. What's the abelianization of $A_5$?

(I'm not really a group theorist)

Comment: It is trivial, but there are two homomorphisms from $A_5$ to $S_5$ (the inclusion and the trivial one).

Comment: In fact there are $120$ nontrivial homomorphisms $A_5 \to S_5$, because you can compose the inclusion with an automorphism.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ahh, right. I was identifying the maps with their images for some strange reason.

Comment: So, it wouldn't be a counterexample right? Because there are only two maps between abelianizations, each of which is surjected onto by some map between A_5 -> S_5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Take $X=C_2=\{1,x\}$ and $Y=Q_8=\{1,i,j,k,-1,-i,-j,-k\}$. Then $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y) = \{ x\mapsto 1, x\mapsto -1\}$ where $x$ is the unique element of order 2 in $X$ and $-1$ is the unique element of order 2 in $Y$. However $X^{ab}=C_2=\{\{1\},\{x\}\}$ and $Y^{ab}=C_2 \times C_2=\{\{\pm1\},\{\pm i\},\{\pm j\},\{\pm k\}\}$ so that $\operatorname{Hom}(X^{ab},Y^{ab}) = \{ \{x\} \mapsto \{ \pm 1 \}, \{x\} \mapsto \{\pm i\}, \{x\} \mapsto \{\pm j\}, \{x\}\mapsto \{\pm k\}\}$ has 4 elements. The image of $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ is only the single map $\{x\} \mapsto \{\pm1\}$.